# SharePoint 2013 - How to make custom list searchable

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, search, custom-list

I pulling list of documents through search results WebPart in SharePoint. 
I am writing this query and it is working fine
`path:"http://server-sharep/abc/*" FileExtension:pdf (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")`

I have created a custom list and attached with the document library and named it **DocumentCategories** and Attached the category from this custom list to specific documents.

Now the issue is, I can't find **DocumentCategories** under '**Property filter**' so I could use the filter and pull specific documents based on the categories.

However, I have doubled check the custom library **DocumentCategories** is searchable as I have checked the settings under `"General Settings > Advanced Settings"`.

What do I have to do in order to make custom list **DocumentCategories** to appear under the filter in Search Result WebParts?

Answer (score 0):

Your "DocumentCategories" must be searchable under generic keyword search, in order to use it in the refiner. 
Find the crawled property for the "DocumentCategories" in the search schema and then create a refinable Managed Property and add this crawled property in the mapping. Use this new managed property in the refiner webpart.

Comment: I tried exactly same thing but still the query is not returning the result based on that. So The Type:Test,Multi:Multi,Query:Query,Search:Search,Retrieve:Retrieve,Refine:Refine,Sort:-,Safe:-,Mapped Crawled Properties:ows_DocumentCategories

Comment: So the category i have in DocumentCategories is for example "abc def gh" and my search query is path:"http://server-sharep/abc/*" FileExtension:pdf (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")   DocumentCategory:abc*

Comment: Do i need to restart IIS or reset anything?

Comment: You need to wait until the next incremental or continuous crawl

Comment: You can also SharePoint Search Query Tool at CodePlex. It is very handy and  easy to use utility that will expose all the properties returned from SP Search. When you start the progra, connect to your sharepoint site  and type in your query and you will see the results where you can inspect all the different props.
https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

Comment: I manually re-indexed the site by going into SITE SETTINGS : SEARCH AND OFFLINE AVAILABILITY. and clicked "Re Index site" button but this still didnt solve the issues

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud, I have installed this tool and ran my query in but if i run the normal query without any filter then it throws the results but if it put the DocumentCategory as filter then it doesnt throw any result. Primary Query Results:
  Total Rows: 0
  Total Rows Including Duplicates: 0
  Query Id: 1a6aadd6-0458-45b0-a803-42dcccb48277
  Query Rule Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  Query Modification: path:"http://server-sharep/abc/*" FileExtension:pdf (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")   DocumentCategories:abc -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople

Answer (score 0):

So you have not mapped the DocumentCategories to RefinableStringxx??? I guess you should map it to RefinableStringxx (providing that DocumentCategory returns text (data type). Once you do that, you should be able to write your query as follows:

```
path:"server-sharep/abc*" FileExtension:pdf (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") RefinableStringxx:abc -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```